# wordwrap php+ cant figure this out

Tags: php, word-wrap, break

I have this php script that does the job perfectly.

However the result that is printed out is on one single line and I need it to be with wordwrap. Limit the line to X amount of characters then start a new line.

I have no idea where to put in the wordwrap command...

(here is the main code)

```
/* Connecting, selecting database */
$link = mysql_connect("XXXXXX", "XXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX") or die("Could not connect : " . mysql_error());
echo "";
mysql_select_db("XXXXXXXX") or die("Could not select database");

/* Performing SQL query */
$result = mysql_query("SELECT XXXXXXXFROM XXXXXXXwhere Date = CURDATE()") or die("SELECT Error: " . mysql_error());
/* $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); */
print "<table border=0 align=center dir=rtl>\n";
while ( $get_info = mysql_fetch_row($result) ) {
    print "<tr>\n<br /><br /><br /><br />";
    foreach ( $get_info as $field )
        print "\t<td><font face=arial size=4/>$field </font></td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```

Comment: what is the field name of where you need wordwrap ??

Answer (score 1):

```
print "\t<td><font face=arial size=4/>".wordwrap($field, 20, '<br />')."</font></td>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can trim of characters in a field (0 - started, 6 - showed 6 characters after first character (0)):

```
print "\t<td><font face=arial size=4/>".substr($field, 0, 6)."</font></td>\n";
```

Comment: sorry didn't do it ....  it just cuts the amount of characters . i dont want it to cut but to jump a line when it reaches an X amount of characters

Answer (score 0):

You should count of strings in a $field for each line and count string of length for this line under defined. If is length in defined limited area this will be print how long it will be.

```
$counted_strings = 0;

foreach ($get_info as $field) 

    $counted_strings = strlen($field);
    $counted_strings++;

    if ($counted_strings <= 30)
    {
        print "\t<td><font face=arial size=4/>$field </font></td>\n"; 
        print "</tr>\n";        
    }

}
```